# URL Based on Text Box Value - MultiLine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code to use a text box to go to a url, adding the value of the textbox at the end of the url.

I want to change this to me a multiline text box. Then for each line in the text box, open a new browser tab with the preset url, plus the line value at the end.

E.g. At the minute if I entered 'test' in the text box it navigates to https://myprofiles.co.uk/name=test

Essentially I just want to copy a list of names into a multime text box and have it open up a browser tab per line. Is someone able to help point me in the right direction please?

```
<form id = "your_form" onsubmit="yourFunction()">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<script>
    function yourFunction(){
        var action_src = "https://www.myprofiles.co.uk/" + 
        document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
        var your_form = document.getElementById('your_form');
        your_form.action = action_src ;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this. Replace the TextBox with a TextArea and add a listener to the button. The button needs to have an ID for that. I've added `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from actual doing a POST. But if you need that then simply remove it.

```
<form id="your_form">
    <textarea name="name"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="your_button">
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementById("your_button").addEventListener("click", function (event) {

        var action_src = "https://www.myprofiles.co.uk/?name=";

        //get the value of the textarea and split by line
        var rows = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value.split(/\r?\n/);

        //loop all the rows
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            //open a new window, could be blocked by browsers
            window.open(action_src + rows[i], "Window" + i);
        }

        //block the posting of the form if needed
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, however this only opens the top line url.

Comment: See my update `window.open(action_src + rows[i], "Window" + i);`, i think it will help.

Comment: Works perfectly. The only issue is. If I have three lines of content, I have to hit the button three times. Is there a way to modify this to only hit the button once and open tabs for all rows and not just one at a time?

Comment: OK, doesn't appear to be working. will check incase I have made a mistake.

Comment: I double checked also. if I enter multiple lines in the textarea it opens the correct windows.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine in IE. Not in chrome/

Comment: It does when you disable the popup blocker.